# bootstrap modal loads html into the CONTENT not BODY

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

According to this source code from bootstrap 3.1.1:

```
 if (this.options.remote) {
      this.$element
        .find('.modal-content')
        .load(this.options.remote, $.proxy(function () {
          this.$element.trigger('loaded.bs.modal')
        }, this))
    }
```

the html fragement loaded from server should be put into the modal body NOT content.

```
$('#myModal').modal({ remote: '@Url.Action("Create","Template")' });
```

The loaded html is put inside the whole dialog content NOT body!

I can fix that for myself changing the source code...

```
if (this.options.remote) {
      this.$element
        .find('.modal-body')
        .load(this.options.remote, $.proxy(function () {
          this.$element.trigger('loaded.bs.modal')
        }, this))
    }
```

**But I do not want to modify bootstraps source code !!!**

[image]

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Thats the partial html fragment:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<form action="/Template/Create" method="post">    <p class="editor-label"><label for="Name">Name</label></p>
    <p class="editor-field"><input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-length="Name must not be longer than 30 chars." data-val-length-max="30" data-val-length-min="1" data-val-remote="This name already exists." data-val-remote-additionalfields="*.Name" data-val-remote-url="/Template/TemplateExists" data-val-required="Name must not be empty" id="Name" name="Name" type="text" value="" /></p>
    <p class="editor-field"><span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Name" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span></p> 
</form>
```

Comment: you can simply load all the content, not just body

Comment: This was an explicit intentional behavior change made in Bootstrap v3.1.0: http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2014/01/30/bootstrap-3-1-0-released/

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand why you so agressive, but obvioulsy that's not stupid, since that's what boostrap is telling you to do.

you have 2 options 1. what you already did:

```
if (this.options.remote) {
  this.$element
    .find('.modal-body')
    .load(this.options.remote, $.proxy(function () {
      this.$element.trigger('loaded.bs.modal')
    }, this))
}
```

the second one, instead of inserting this:

```
<form action="/Template/Create" method="post">    
    <p class="editor-label"><label for="Name">Name</label></p>
    <p class="editor-field"><input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-length="Name must not be longer than 30 chars." data-val-length-max="30" data-val-length-min="1" data-val-remote="This name already exists." data-val-remote-additionalfields="*.Name" data-val-remote-url="/Template/TemplateExists" data-val-required="Name must not be empty" id="Name" name="Name" type="text" value="" /></p>
    <p class="editor-field"><span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Name" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span></p>
</form>
```

you can just insert this (that's what bs script is wating for)

```
<div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form><!--your form here!--></form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
```

hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue just now. I forgot to include some bootstrap js files. If anyone will have the same issue, here are scripts which fixed this problem for me:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap-modal/js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap-modal/js/bootstrap-modalmanager.js"></script>
```